# get data from api in nodemailer node.js config

Tags: node.js, api, express, nodemailer

I'm trying to create a sender config nodemailer node.js, that is fetched dynamic data coming from API,
example:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: fromAPI,
port: fromAPI,
secure: fromAPI,
auth: {
    user: fromAPI,
    pass: fromAPI
}});
```

"fromAPI" it's dynamic data coming from api

I tried to build from axios but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4500/api/email_config', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer mytoken`,
        },
    }) 
 .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data); 
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Does "fromAPI" for host mean `response.data.host` etc ?

Comment: yes, like response.data.host

Answer (score 1):

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: data.host,
port: fromAPI,
secure: fromAPI,
auth: {
    user: data.user,
    pass: data.pass
}});
```

have you tried like this?